# Where are Pillars of Eternity portraits located on OSX?

Tags: steam, macos, pillars-of-eternity

I have some custom portraits downloaded and need to put them in some directory but have no idea where the portrait directory is on OSX (game installed from Steam).

I've tried `~/Library/Application Support/Pillars of Eternity` but no luck, they aren't there.

Comment: I managed to answer my own question while writing this but thought it could be useful for some other people and decided to post it anyway together with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are here: `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity.app/Contents/Data/art/gui/portraits`

To actually get to this directory, open the terminal (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and type `terminal`) and execute:

```
open ~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Pillars\ of\ Eternity/PillarsOfEternity.app/Contents/Data/art/gui/portraits/
```

Comment: Can't seem to find it.  Running 10.9.5.  Any advice?  How did you find it?

Comment: @AlexSalazar, I have edited the answer, see if that helps.